# Joint Probability Distribution and covariance

Tags: probability, self-study, covariance, joint-distribution

If $$f(x,y)=1/4 $$ $x=-3,y=-5; x=-1,y=-1;  x=1,y=1; x=3,y=5. $Find 
cov (x,y).

I know  the formula for cov (X,Y) but I'm stuck at finding E (x) and E (y).

Comment: Use the definition of expectation.

Comment: @whuber Is E (x)=0= E (y)?

Comment: To apply the definition to $x,$ make a table of all the values of $x$ and their probabilities, then sum the products of the values and their probabilities.

Comment: @whuber does each x have same probability i.e equal to 1/4?

Comment: Apparently--one has to presume this--the values of $f$ give the probabilities.